# How to replace dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries. The first one is **"dict_postion"** and the second one is **"dict_items"**. I want to replace keys in "dict_items" based on "dict_position". Sort out the first dictionary (dict_position) value in ascending order, based on this order, rearrange/replace the corresponding keys in both of the dictionaries.

I want to replace the old key with the new key as below :

```
 {'lbl301(oldkey)': 'lbl301(newkey)', 'lbl302(oldkey)': 'lbl305(newkey)', 'lbl303(oldkey)': 'lbl302(newkey)', 'lbl304(oldkey)': 'lbl303(newkey)', 'lbl305(oldkey)': 'lbl304(newkey)'}
```

For more clearance, I attach a screenshot of the expected result.

```
dict_position = {'user_03':{'lbl301':[0,0,1,1],'lbl302':[0,2,1,1],'lbl303':[1,0,1,1],
                                'lbl304':[1,1,1,1],'lbl305':[0,1,1,1]}}
    
   
dict_items = {'id': {'lbl301': 'select', 'lbl302': 'Create','lbl303':'modify',   'lbl304':'backup',   'lbl305':'settings'},
               'A': {'lbl301':'Select_A','lbl302':'Create_A','lbl303':'Modify_A','lbl304':'Back Up_A','lbl305':'settings_A'},
               'B': {'lbl301':'Select_B','lbl302':'Create_B','lbl303':'Modify_B','lbl304':'Back Up_B','lbl305':'settings_B'},
               'C': {'lbl301':'Select_C','lbl302':'Create_C','lbl303':'Modify_C','lbl304':'Back Up_C','lbl305':'settings_C'}}

    
    working_dict_temp,wid_position_dict_temp = {},{}
    wid_position_list = []
    
    for key, item in dict_position['user_03'].items():
        working_dict_temp.update({str(item): key})
        if item not in wid_position_list:
            wid_position_list.append(item)
    wid_position_list.sort()
    
    for a, b in enumerate(wid_position_list):
        old_key = 'lbl' + str(300 + (a + 1))+"(oldkey)"
        new_key = working_dict_temp[str(b)] + "(newkey)"
        wid_position_dict_temp.update({old_key: new_key})
    print(wid_position_dict_temp)
```

**Expected result :**

```
dict_position = {'user_03':{'lbl301':[0,0,1,1],'lbl303':[0,2,1,1],'lbl304':[1,0,1,1],
                            'lbl305':[1,1,1,1],'lbl302':[0,1,1,1]}}

dict_items = {'id': {'lbl301': 'select','lbl303': 'Create' ,'lbl304':'modify','lbl305':'backup','lbl302':'settings'},
             'A': {'lbl301':'Select_A','lbl303':'Create_A','lbl304':'Modify_A','lbl305':'Back Up_A','lbl302':'settings_A'},
             'B': {'lbl301':'Select_B','lbl303':'Create_B','lbl304':'Modify_B','lbl305':'Back Up_B','lbl302':'settings_B'},
             'C': {'lbl301':'Select_C ','lbl303':'Create_C','lbl304':'Modify_C','lbl305':'Back Up_C','lbl302':'settings_C'},
```

Comment: What is the relevance of the `'user_03'` key? I assume that just happens to be the key that holds the ordering you're interested in? Also, can you explain how something like `'lbl301':[0,0,1,1]` translates to the relative positions in the required output? It's not obvious.

Comment: based on user selection, i need to rearrange the widgets in pyqt5.  some users need the first widget to display last one, And some other need to display at 3rd position . @Grismar

Comment: @ Grismar, lbl305 is replaced by lbl302 and lbl 302 is replaced by 303, for clearence attach wich label is replaced by wich label -------->  {'lbl301': 'lbl301_new', 'lbl302': 'lbl305_new', 'lbl303': 'lbl302_new', 'lbl304': 'lbl303_new', 'lbl305': 'lbl304_new'}

Comment: It remains unclear what you're trying to do here, or what exactly the problem is. You're moving some data around and relabeling it, and you have some code that does this - but what the logic is supposed to be and how the desired output relates to or follows from the starting data is unclear. Perhaps you should simplify the problem, or explain exactly what it is about your current result you want to change.

Comment: @Grismar, I need to replace the current key  (old_key) with a new_key. The new _key will derive from the dictionary "dict_position" in ascending order. If I rearrange/replace the keys from old to new then only I run my script as I Expected.

Comment: You've made some edits and say you just want to replace old keys with new keys, but the order of values in your desired result appears to be different from the order in the original data as well - it's not just a relabelling of your dictionary (which is fairly straightforward). Please try and make clear not just what the result should look like, but *how that follows from the data*.

Answer (score 0):

Just relabeling a dictionary is straightforward:

```
def remap(d, mapping):
    return {mapping[k]: v for k, v in d.items()}


mapping = {'lbl301': 'lbl301', 'lbl302': 'lbl305', 'lbl303': 'lbl302', 'lbl304': 'lbl303', 'lbl305': 'lbl304'}
dict_position['user_03'] = remap(dict_position['user_03'], mapping)
```

However, that outcome is not what you say you want as an outcome - it's unclear what logic you're applying to come up with the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem in this way. But I am not sure it's a Pythonic way or not.

```
dict_position = {'user_03':{'lbl301':[0,0,1,1],'lbl302':[0,2,1,1],'lbl303':[1,0,1,1],
                            'lbl304':[1,1,1,1],'lbl305':[0,1,1,1]}}

dict_items = {'id': {'lbl301': 'select', 'lbl302': 'Create','lbl303':'modify',   'lbl304':'backup',   'lbl305':'settings'},
               'A': {'lbl301':'Select_A','lbl302':'Create_A','lbl303':'Modify_A','lbl304':'Back Up_A','lbl305':'settings_A'},
               'B': {'lbl301':'Select_B','lbl302':'Create_B','lbl303':'Modify_B','lbl304':'Back Up_B','lbl305':'settings_B'},
               'C': {'lbl301':'Select_C','lbl302':'Create_C','lbl303':'Modify_C','lbl304':'Back Up_C','lbl305':'settings_C'}}

working_dict_temp,wid_position_dict_temp = {},{}
wid_position_list = []

for key, item in dict_position['user_03'].items():
    working_dict_temp.update({str(item): key})
    if item not in wid_position_list:
        wid_position_list.append(item)
wid_position_list.sort()

for a, b in enumerate(wid_position_list):
    old_key = 'lbl' + str(300 + (a + 1))
    new_key = working_dict_temp[str(b)] +"_newkey"
    wid_position_dict_temp.update({old_key: new_key})
    dict_position['user_03'][new_key] = dict_position['user_03'].pop(old_key)
    for item_keys in dict_items.keys():
        dict_items[item_keys][new_key] = dict_items[item_keys].pop(old_key)

for key,value in wid_position_dict_temp.items():
    new_key = value.split("_")[0]
    dict_position['user_03'][new_key] = dict_position['user_03'].pop(value)
    for item_keys in dict_items.keys():
        dict_items[item_keys][new_key] = dict_items[item_keys].pop(value)
```